# Username must be at least 8 characters and must be a combination of letters and numbers

Tags: angular, typescript

Do match is working on typescript if yes how to use it?
 I need to use something that can fixed my problem on username.
 Username must be at least 8 characters and must be a combination of letters and numbers.

```
ValidateUsername() {
if(this.SignUp.Username.match(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)){

}else
{
  this.MessageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Message', detail: 'Username must be at least 8 characters and must be a combination of letters and numbers!' });
  return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
private regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/;

ValidateUsername() {
    if (this.regext.test(this.username)) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: No worries! It would be helpful if you accept the answer. Thanks!